# Absence and presence of curly brace in "if" statement

Tags: javascript

```
var i = 0, 
    j = 8;

checkiandj: while (i < 4) {
    console.log("i: " + i); 
    i += 1; // i=1;

    checkj: while (j > 4) { //j=8
        console.log("j: "+ j); 
        j -= 1;  // 7
        if ((j % 2) == 0)  
            continue checkj;
        console.log(j + " is odd.");
    }
    console.log("i = " + i);
    console.log("j = " + j);
}
```

How does this part of the code works?

```
       if ((j % 2) == 0)  
            continue checkj;
        console.log(j + " is odd.");
```

Is it like this?

```
if ((j % 2) == 0)  
    continue checkj; 
else
    console.log(j + " is odd.");
```

or like this?

```
if ((j % 2) == 0)  {
    continue checkj; 
}
console.log(j + " is odd.");
```

And if I will read this statement(original one) at first look, I will understand it as: if Divide modulo 2 equal zero , do both `continue checkj` and `console.log`, not only `continue`. I know that what makes "continue" , but it`s hard to understand this action without curly braces. How can I understand better absence of curly braces?

Comment: Not sure this is a good question. If you always use blocks you're unlikely to be confused by their absence. ;-) Generally where a block is used for structures like conditions and loops, only the immediately following statement is considered part of the block if no braces are present to define the block.

Comment: so what purpose does `continue checkj;` serve? Is it just to make it clearer for yourself?

Comment: An if statements without "curly braces" (as you referred to them) simply executes the next statement if the condition in the `if` evaluates to `true`. If you have braces, then each statements within the braces is evaluated with the condition is `true`. It is only coincidental that the two statements you mention are equivalent, and that is only because you are escaping the current while loop with a continue statement (Incidentally, using labels and continue with label references is not good practice.).